How can i Adding hours to a selected hour in SwiftUI to transform local hours in to Zulu hours
Does anyone can help me or point me in the right direction in order to adding hours to get Zulu hours from a selected time for example i have this peace of code:
struct datepicker: View {
    @State var startTime: Date = .now
    @State var zuluTime = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DatePicker("_", selection: $startTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                .labelsHidden()
          Text(zuluTime)
        }
        .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: "da"))
    }
}

This code gives the time in 24 format but i want to display also the Zulu time
for example if you have 19:00 the zulu times adds or substract hours depending on your time zone if your at UTC + 5 you have to add 5 hours to the time 19:00 - > 00:00 (of next day)
thanks in advance for any help or tip

Look for a well-used library of date functions - what you describe sounds simple, but dates are notoriously difficult to do correctly - even just adding one hour is problematic when DST changes, for example.

Try this approach using a DateFormatter, such as:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var startTime: Date = .now
    
    var formatter: DateFormatter {
        let frmt = DateFormatter()
        frmt.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mm"
        frmt.locale = Locale(identifier: "da")
        frmt.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC") // zulu (UTC) time
        return frmt
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DatePicker("_", selection: $startTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                .labelsHidden()
                .datePickerStyle(.wheel)
            Text(formatter.string(from: startTime)) // zulu (UTC) time
        }
        .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: "da"))
    }
}

Or this:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var startTime: Date = .now
    @State private var zuluTime = ""
    
    var formatter: DateFormatter {
        let frmt = DateFormatter()
        frmt.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
        frmt.locale = Locale(identifier: "da")
        frmt.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC") // zulu (UTC) time
        return frmt
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DatePicker("_", selection: $startTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                .labelsHidden()
                .datePickerStyle(.wheel)
            Text(zuluTime) // zulu (UTC) time
            Text(startTime, style: .time) // local time
        }
        .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: "da"))
        .onChange(of: startTime) {
            zuluTime = formatter.string(from: startTime)
        }
        .onAppear {
            zuluTime = formatter.string(from: startTime)
        }
    }
}

